# search for variable in expect response using regex

Tags: regex, expect

I am trying to get number of a server using expect
I tried both of the following but it isnt working, does anyone have a solution?

`expect -re {([0-9]*), Name: $server}`
`expect -re {([0-9]*), Name: \$server}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expect is an extension of [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl), and Tcl uses braces for quoting without interpolation (like the way the shell uses single quotes). To allow for variable expansion, you need to use double quotes. However double quotes also allow command substitution, which Tcl uses square brackets for. You need to do this:

```
expect -re "(\[0-9]*), Name $server"
```

But you don't need to use a regex bracket expression for digits:

```
expect -re "(\\d*), Name $server"
```

The backslash is doubled due to using double quotes.